# Store material as vertex attribute

Tags: opengl

I'm rendering multiple objects with multiple material. Usually material is represented as uniform in shader, and to render the whole scene we call draw for each material.

Can I represent material (Kd, Ka etc) as vertex attribute and send it to fragment shader with flat interpolation? This way we can draw with just a single command. What is the disadvantage of this approach?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Disadvantage: More GPU memory required.

Comment: Consider `glVertexAttribDivisor` to reduce the memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this; simply define the material as a vertex attribute just as you would for color, normal, or position.  I wouldn't worry too much about sending 2 extra floats (diffuse, ambient) per vertex to a modern graphics card. There might be a slight performance difference, but not much. If this is what you need, then using a vertex attribute is the cleanest approach.